# Generalizing an existing theorem which is true for compact state space to Polish state space under stronger/new assumptions

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I have a general question. Suppose I am generalizing an existing theorem which is true for compact state space to Polish state space. Is it always better to have a stronger assumptions than the earlier work than having a completely new set of assumptions. I mean one has to justify assumptions, in the former case one can justify it better.

Comment: The generalized result has weaker assumptions, not stronger ones.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: I think OP means by general is extending from compact to Polish. Therefore it may have restrictive conditions to prove the theorem for Polish.